# Erro ao instanciar em Java

Tags: java

No meu curso sobre Java OO, eu montei um classe para executar certas funções. Mas sempre retornam NullPointException. Se eu fizer a mesma coisa dentro do metodo `main`, sem criar classe alguma, tudo funciona numa boa.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Trecho que da erro usando a clase que criei:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // write your code here

        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setMovieFile("movies.txt");

        System.out.println(movie.getMovieListSize());
    }
}
```

---

Se eu fizer a mesma coisa dentro dentro do `Main()`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // write your code here

       File file = new File("movies.txt");
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

       if (scanner.hasNextLine()){
           System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
       }
    }
}
```

---

E está é a classe que escrevi e todo objeto retorna erro:

```
public class Movie {

   private List<String> movies;
   private File file;
   private Scanner scanner;
   private boolean hasSetted;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public void setMovieFile(String movieFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        file = new File(movieFile);
        scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            movies.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        hasSetted = true;
    }

    public String getMovie(int position){
        return movies.get(position);
    }

    public int getMovieListSize(){
        return movies.size();
    }

}
```

---

Esse código está no github tbm:
https://github.com/sshnakamoto/MovieGuess

Comment: nullpointer em qual linha?

Comment: Você não inicializou o campo `movies`, deve fazê-lo no construtor.

Comment: Faltou instanciar `movies`. Ele está apenas declarado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variável `movies` nunca foi instanciada, portanto, você está tentando adicionar um filme a uma variavel nula e nao a uma lista vazia.

Instancie corretamente a lista, sugiro que o faça no construtor:

```
public Movie() {
   movies = new ArrayLis<>();
}
```